# ColdFusion Query Of query

Tags: sql, coldfusion, coldfusion-8, qoq

This query:

```
SELECT * FROM getlogs WHERE id > #id# AND logType = "login" LIMIT 1
```

Gives me this error:

```
Error Executing Database Query.


Query Of Queries syntax error.
Encountered "logType. Incorrect conditional expression, Incorrect conditional expression, Lexical error at line 0, column 0. Encountered: "\"" (34), after : ""
```

Comment: For what database?  PostgreSQL, MySQL and SQLite are the only ones I know of that support `LIMIT`, but that doesn't look like it's the issue (or getting that far).  Is there a column called "logtype" in the `getlogs` table?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use max rows:

< cfquery dbType="query" name"myQ" maxrows="1">
SELECT * FROM getlogs WHERE id > #id# AND logType = "login"
< /cfquery>

Comment: @Bubby you should accept this one rather than mine - he actually told you how to fix it, not just what was wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Use single quotes instead of double quotes.

Comment: They should add that in the documentation, also, can I use limit?

Comment: @Bubby It is - check the mysql docs.  After all, that's the database you're using.  It's also part of the ansi-92 sql spec.

Comment: `Error Executing Database Query.
Query Of Queries syntax error.
Encountered "LIMIT"` Yeah I'm sure it does >.>

Comment: @Bubby, ah, then you're not using mysql. What database engine are you talking to?

Comment: The ColdFusion query of queries database, It's a thing that coldfusion has where you can run a SQL statment (I think it's custom to ColdFusion?) on a query object. http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=using_recordsets_7.html#1137985

Comment: There's no support for "LIMIT" mentioned there anywhere.